# How to add integer as default/initial value for TextFormField in flutter?

Tags: flutter, form-fields

This will work

```
TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController(text:"this works");
```

but this does not

```
TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController(text:123);
```

It shows this error:

> The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

But I’m not able to change the type to int for `TextFormField`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TextEditingController` only accepts `String`, so you have to convert your number to `String`.

```
TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController(text:123.toString());
```

or

```
TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController(text:"123");
```